# Remove autoban from downvote on old question after previous autoban

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I finally got my question ban removed, but someone just downvoted me for a question I asked last February and now I'm banned again. Can you guys take that out of the algorithm please? That's really not fair.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted for this now? Is this not a valid feature request?

Comment: Life isn't fair. Seems you'll have to improve more of your questions.

Comment: votes on feature-requests are approve/disaprove as well as valid/not valid. can be confusing.

Comment: You shouldn't get a ban removed and then put back because some random dude is browsing questions from almost a year ago

Comment: @NickManning No, it is not a valid feature request.

Comment: _"Is this not a valid feature request?"_ Certainly not a [tag:feature-request]! [tag:support] or [tag:discussion] seem to be more appropriate. _"some random dude"_ Hey, hey, hey! We're all of these _random dudes_ here, dude!

Comment: Seems like at least one of the two questions that were recently downvoted could easily be improved upon and salvaged.

Comment: I cannot believe that it only took one single solitary downvote to get banned again. Take note everyone that I figured out the algorithm: it's one downvote on a question from 7 months ago when I first learned about the site...that will cause your 3rd ban after you spend days answering questions to get it back.

Comment: @NickManning no, there's two downvotes. But they were both from earlier this year.

Comment: Well, I upvoted a couple of questions that I thought were OK, and you're still banned.  Seems it's not about that single downvote.

Comment: Whoever just upvoted my questions...thanks!!! Now I'm not banned anymore.

Comment: _"Whoever "_ @RobertHarvey disclosed ;) ...

Comment: Oh wait nevermind...it allowed me to ask on meta but not on the stackoverflow site. But seriously...I only got one downvote and it caused me to get banned.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Now people are downvoting more of my answers to troll my account.

Comment: @NickManning It's not about the single downvote.  Q-bans don't happen from a single vote.  You've obviously got some content out there that the community feels is low-quality and they are voting on it.  Edit your questions and try to improve the content.

Comment: Then how can you explain that I got unbanned, then didn't do anything except get a downvote for a question I asked months ago, and now I'm banned again?

Comment: Yeah because since I asked this question I got more downvotes on random questions I had asked in months past

Comment: Your overall balance will fall right on the edge of being banned/unbanned. A single vote might tip the balance, but it won't by itself cause a ban or unban.

Comment: @NickManning _"Now people are downvoting more ..."_ As mentioned: "Life isn't fair.", and that's a well known side effect, when you're asking such stuff on Meta SO.

Comment: Could expect some of the votes to be reversed since they were made after visiting your profile, not guaranteed of course.

Comment: @NickManning _" to troll my account"_ What makes you so sure about they're trolling? It could well be some of the downvoters (I'm not one of them here), just went to review your questions and gave a honest judgement?

Comment: @RobertHarvey You realize you just admitted to serial upvoting of a user because he posted an unconstructive rant about the consequences of his own behavior.

Comment: Because why would people downvote my questions from months ago right after I asked this question? My questions might not be the works of art but they are sufficient questions for this site. Anyway, I just got unbanned (really this time) so thanks again upvoters!

Comment: @JayBlanchard when didn't I accept an answer?

Comment: 'Sufficient' is a judgement call that many have said 'wasn't'. On SO? Numerous times.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for that astute observation, but I doubt that two upvotes constitutes serial upvoting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The definition of serial upvoting is upvoting the user, not the content.  The quantity is merely the flawed mechanism by which SE can actually attempt to determine when that's the case.  So just because the SE automated reversal won't be able to tell that you were voting for the user and not the content doesn't mean that it's not exactly what that script is there to prevent.

Comment: Maybe he liked my answers!

Comment: @NickManning He specifically said that he went to your profile to upvote your posts because you're banned.  That's freely admitting to doing exactly what the rules state is not allowed.  Rules that he has been elected to enforce, I might add.  In fact, it's his job to specifically investigate instances of voting fraud that aren't caught by the automated scripts and reverse them; instances such as the one he just admitted to.

Comment: No he said "that I thought were OK".

Comment: @NickManning Which is no more appropriate, according to the rules.  Going out and finding posts from a particular user to upvote is defined as voting fraud.

Comment: @NickManning That last comment of yours (you well know which one) was definitely rude and absolutely incorrect!!

Comment: @Servy to get on his case like this...you'd be the type of cop to pull someone over for going 66 in a 65. He probably saw my question and wanted to check my profile to see what is up. He probably agreed with me after seeing my profile that I got the wrong end of the deal on this mysterious algorithm, and upvoted a few that he saw. Are you proud of yourself for taking these arbitrary stack overflow rules as revelation from the divine?

Comment: PS...I went to a meeting and returned to TONS of downvoted on all my questions...but I still have +9 for the day. Why does the algorithm take downvotes more seriously than real stack overflow?

Comment: @NickManning just give it a rest. These comments are going nowhere. Focus on getting out of your ban. At least you know you're close, and you've received some good tips. Move on.

Comment: @Bart to be honest I'm complaining so that they change stack overflow...not for myself. Also, I got way more downvotes since so now I'm not even close.

Comment: That moment you're complaining about not being able to use a free website based on fake Internet points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hm. If that's the case, a single upvote should lift you out again. Or an undownvote.

Yes, I concede it feels somewhat like a betrayal as you just got it done, but that's a case of life ain't always feeling fair, and there are always edge-cases.

As long as you are hanging from your finger-tips, it's just a fact of life that anything has effects quite out of proportion compared to normal.

Keep faith, you are nearly there.

Answer (score 20):

My advice in these situations is always the same:

**Edit your questions.**

All of them. The ones that've been downvoted, the ones that haven't been upvoted, the ones that've gotten a mix... Do a thorough review. Remember, the whole idea behind Stack Overflow is that these questions stick around, potentially for *years*, so that others can benefit from the time someone put into addressing a problem you faced - so it's always a good idea to make sure that folks who share the problems you've faced can **find them**.

- Make the titles clear and specific
- Make sure formatting is attractive and easy to read
- Fix egregious spelling and grammar errors

Anything you can do to make sure folks' first impression of your question is one that focuses on *the problem* you were trying to solve... Not the way in which you presented it.

With 30+ questions under your belt, I imagine there are more than few that could use a bit of tidying - consider it an investment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62139/discussion-on-answer-by-shog9-remove-autoban-from-downvote-on-old-question-after).

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I should have to edit all these questions. They are not works of art but they are fine in my opinion. If there's a question you think completely sucks...let me know which one. People just browse the site and downvote, taking it very lightly. And then this algorithm bans me.

Comment: You don't *have* to do anything. But should you *want* to do something, that's my advice.

Comment: I want to ask questions.

Answer (score 7):

An automatic question ban is not applied lightly. If someone downvotes an old question, that means you haven't improved that question enough yet, or it is just such a bad fit you can't possibly improve it. You should have prevented being autobanned in the first place, not complain about the algorithm banning you again after someone voted. The autoban-algorithm keeps Stack Overflow cleaner than it otherwise would be. Please [read this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: The automatic question ban is applied lightly. -1

Comment: Look at my account if you don't believe it is applied lightly. I don't have any deleted questions off the top of my head.

Comment: I don't have the 10k tools, so I can't see if you have any deleted answers or questions. The focus on my answer is that the algorithm for autobans keeps StackOverflow cleaner, and that the linked question will tell you how to proceed from here. The downvote that pushed you over the edge again is not to blame, your previous behaviour that caused the original question ban caused it.

Comment: [Too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21638772/2209007), [no code to reproduce it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21594689/2209007), [far too broad question; focus on the problem at hand instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21342579/2209007), [viewer bait (attracts views, but it helps no-one and attracts no votes whatsoever)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18912189/2209007), [another viewer bait](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16029377/2209007), [don't put a paragraph of text in the title](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20750750/2209007). Go through your questions without accepted answers/downvoted questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but to get banned twice, only to exert effort having it lifted by answering questions, only to have some random googler downvote a question from almost a year ago, to ban me again is stupid (after getting my ban lifted, one downvote rebanned me). Are you seriously accusing me of "viewer bait"? I have better things to do. And I didn't accept answers on questions because they were not the correct answer!!!!! As for the ones that are "too broad"...maybe this is a fair criticism of my questions but am I worthy of three bans (not being even close to be taken out of my third).

Comment: This is why stackoverflow gets such a reputation for having bitchy users. Take a look at my profile, not searching for faults, and you will find a relatively decent profile. Maybe one day every other question on meta wont be "hey guys...can we be a little nicer?"

Comment: I just improved one of my questions by answering the question that no one had given a sufficient answer to, and choosing my own answer as correct.

Comment: I use "viewer bait" to describe a situation where a question attracts a lot of views, but does not help that many users. In other words: "The contents of the question, or more likely, the title, does not accurately describe the problem.". In other words: "You should rewrite it.". If you don't get the answer you are looking for on a question, might that mean that the question was not asked correctly in the first place? Your profile is not completely crap - and I have given you some upvotes for some of your q's and a's. You can however improve several of your questions.

Comment: As for the rest: A its-your-fault-I-dont-need-to-fix-my-questions-you-have-to-unban-me-now-because-its-unfair-altitude will not get you unbanned.

Comment: nothing will get me unbanned because people are downvoting me on all my questions now. I'm editing a few of my posts here and there but I still maintain that I should not have been banned in the first place, let alone three times.